# Smartface in action project does not load

Tags: smartface.io

I could not open the smartface in action project on 4.4 beta version. Then I tried it on 4.3, but I got an error that the project is corrupted.

How can I open that project?

Comment: Are you trying to open Smartface in Action from the Welcome tab in Smartface App studio?

Comment: of course, when I open the project on the Smartface App Studio, the main screen is looked like a white page.

Comment: Because some parts of the code are dynamic. There is no static design for pgBlog which is showed at the opening.